# Can "insert reference" function searching external file in texshop?

Tags: cross-referencing, include, texshop

I am using Texshop under Lion. I am writing a thesis which contains many chapters as separated files and I use "include" in the main file. In Texshop, one can directly insert reference by "cmd+shift+r" which pops out a list containing all the labels within the range of this file. But what I want is to access the labels in another file(chapter) in the scope of the thesis. So what should I do or is there any other softwares can do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems more like a feature request in TeXshop (software) than it is about (La)TeX.